# What is the probability of drawing 3 balls such that none of them is red?

Tags: probability

> Given a bag containing $8\ \color{red}{red}$ balls and $4\ \color{green}{green}$ balls,
>
> what is the probability of drawing $3$ balls at random such that $\mathbf {none}$ of them are $\color{red}{red}$?

---

My Approach:

$$1-(\ P(Balls_{\color{red}{red}}\ge 1)+P(Balls_{\color{red}{red}}\ge 2)+P(Balls_{\color{red}{red}}\ge 3)\ )$$

$$1 - \left({8 \choose 1} {4 \choose 3} + {8 \choose 2} {4 \choose 1} + {8 \choose 3} {4 \choose 0}\right)= -423$$

$$Total\ possible\ ways={12 \choose 3}$$

Answer given:

$$\frac{4}{495}$$

---

I am getting the wrong answer and I don't know why. Please correct my work and tell me if there are any alternate approaches that I could use.

Comment: Try finding  *directly*,  P(3 green balls)

Comment: @trueblueanil but that could be only possible if i select 3 green balls from 4.Why the above approach doesn't work i want to learn.

Comment: @Jack-How is denominator coming 495.Total possible outcomes=12c3=220.

Comment: Well, the question asks exactly that (draw 3 balls). Why do you want to do it the long way ? Your equation has so many errors that I don't know where to start !

Comment: I would say $P = 4/12 * 3/11 * 2/10=1/55$ (drawing without replacement).

Comment: @georg-Do you think the answer is wrong?I also agree with you and think it is wrong.I have also mentioned an alternate way in the answer section.

Comment: @tatan Ans is wrong yes i also think the same.

Comment: @trueblueanil i understood the events are not independent.i don't want to do it in the long way probably i would have used this approach somewhere else too without knowing the basic fact.

Comment: If answer given is 4/495, then the problem given is wrong.

Comment: @trueblueanil or may be the Ans?

Comment: Yea, I meant if the *correct* answer is 4/495, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are summing events prob which are not independent, see there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability
and the approach given in comments by @true blue and using the very same theorem could lead you to the correct probability, with a three steps process, first draw : you get a green, same for second, etc, updating the odds with the right numbers of balls.

Comment: Seems your are new to Maths SE.Please consider writing these in the comment box and not in the answer because it does not answer his question.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this fact, though my reputation does not allow me to comment and the fact that the OP wanted explanations on how his answer was wrong I posted this, trying to be didactic and not giving the entire answer. I back your solution, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Directly, Pr = $\dfrac{4\choose3}{12\choose3} = \dfrac{1}{55}$

In the tortuous way you were attempting,

Pr = 1 - $\dfrac{{8\choose3}{4\choose0} +{8\choose2}{4\choose1} +{8\choose 1}{4\choose2}}{12\choose3} = \dfrac{1}{55} $

Answer (score 2):

The total no. of ways in which green balls can be chosen $={4\choose 3}$.

The total no. of ways in which balls can be chosen $={12\choose 3}$

> Probability that the balls will not be red(i.e., they will be green)$= \frac{4\choose 3}{12\choose 3}=\frac{1}{55}$.

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense.  It looks like you meant the total number of ways in which three balls can be selected from twelve balls is $\binom{12}{3} = 220$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig-I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of randomly drawing 3 balls not red would mean selecting green balls such that there is a combination of 4 green balls from which we can choose 3 divided by the combination of 12 balls, green and red, choosing 3 green balls at random therefore:

> 4C3 / 12C3 = 1/55 or 0.0182